# Javascript scroll bar, go to bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

I'm currently coding a PHP and MYSQL chat. The chat messages are held in a div with the class '.chat'. It has a overflow:auto css element so it has a vertical scrollbar. I would like it so when you join the chat, it starts the scrollbar at the bottom.

I currently have the following code so far:

```
$(".chat").animate({ scrollTop: '7807897px' }, "fast");
```

This method doesn't always work, and can really become annoying. I know there must be an easier way out there, I'm just new to javascript and would really love some help :)

Thanks a lot

EDIT: My .chat div has a 80% height element. So the scroll by height doesn't seem to work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not get the height of `.chat` ?

```
$(".chat").animate({
    scrollTop: $('.chat').height() 
}, "fast");
```

If your scrolling the page you can use

```
$(document).height();
```

Comment: Any idea on how to make this work on Iphone browsers? It just scrolls half way for some reason!

Works great other than the mobile issue though :)

Comment: Is it because of the iphone menu bar that appears when you load the page, then dissapears? ( does the height difference match the height of the iphone menu bar), if not you could try **`outerHeight()`**

Comment: On my computer, after 10 messages, it stops working. Everytime i go to the page it goes to the middle of the scroll-bar instead of the bottom

Comment: Here is my CSS - .chat {
 padding: 14px 0;
 height: 62%; 
 overflow: auto;
 margin-top: 5px;
}

and here is the javascript: 

    $(".chat").animate({ scrollTop: $('.chat').height() }, "fast");

When i refresh the page, it goes to the middle like this: http://i.imgur.com/nvK7Wqw.png

You can check the code here: http://rawrlike.me/ username: demo password: demo

Comment: try this `$(".chat").animate({ scrollTop: $('.chat')[0].scrollHeight }, "fast");`

Comment: That works when I post something, but when I refresh the page, it either doesn't move, or goes in the middle

Comment: You're going to have to come up with some sort of demo, otherwise I can't help you.

Comment: The scrollHeight does work, but i think it could be because the chat hasn't fully loaded, try and put it in a 5 second timeout and see what happens

Comment: Yeah that seems to have fixed it. It was just the loading times. :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

raplace:

```
$(".chat").animate({ scrollTop: '7807897px' }, "fast");
```

on:

```
$(".chat").animate({ scrollTop: $('.chat').height() }, "fast");
```